# Are secret hats limited to one per SE site or only one for entire SE winter Bash

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2014, secret-hats

Are secret hats limited to Entire Winter bash 2014 of Stack exchange or they will be awarded in all SE sites?

Edit: I mean earning of secret hats

Comment: What do you mean by "Entire Winter bash"?

Comment: Hats go away when the winter bash ends.

Answer (score 6):

All hats, both normal and secret hats, are obtainable on all sites, and once you get it on one site, it will synchronise to all sites that you participate. Of course, if you chose to opt out from the Winter Bash 2014 event, then there will be no hats on the site that you chose to opt out. (PS: Thanks, nicael.)

Quote from the blog post of Winter Bash 2014:

> Once you acquire an item, click your avatar to pick a hat that you earned—not just on the current site, but anywhere.

This proves that hats are cross-site.

Another way to prove this? You can just complete the Chameleon secret hat mission (changes your profile picture) and you should see a bunch of notifications saying:

> You earned Chameleon on [site which you logged in]!

Remember, if you ticked the box saying "only on this site", then click "wear hat", then you will only wear the hat on that specific site.

[image]

This is the [blog post of Winter Bash 2014](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/12/winter-bash-2014/?cb=1), you can find all the information you need.

Comment: Small correction: on all the sites which hadn't opt out of the hatz.

Comment: I mean that entire site can opt out of hatz and then you won't have an ability to enable them there (e.g. http://mathoverflow.net)

Comment: Oh, so it's still site based?

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 yes it's site based, each site does have its own leaderboard as well. :)

Answer (score 3):

Hats can only be awarded on participating sites. If a site doesn't participate in the Winter Bash, you cannot earn a hat there either. Secret or no secret.

Hats earned on one site can be donned anywhere on the network; if you earned a hat on site A, you can wear it on site B, provided site B is participating, of course. This includes the secret hats; the hat I am wearing at the time of this post was earned on Stack Overflow, but you can see I am wearing it here.

All hats can be earned anywhere on the SE network, *with the exception of 1 of the secret hats*. Eureka is awarded manually only to the *first* person to explain how to earn one of the 8 secret hats. Most of these were awarded on here on Meta.SE, with the exception of one hat for [Logan M](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/users/58/logan-m#winter-bash) who I think must've spoken with a developer in a Moderator-only chat room instead (there is no public record of his revelation that I can find).

The [Winterbash Leaderboard](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/leaderboard) has one overall ranking for sites earned *anywhere*, and per-site rankings where only hats earned *on that site* are counted.

Comment: Lets say some ABC.SE is participating in Winter bash 2014, are all the 8 secret hats are available for grab in that SE site

Comment: @strikers yes, they are.

Comment: Nice boat you have there ;)

Comment: @Oded: sailing the seas of the interwebz!

Comment: @ShadowWizard: one secret hat is awarded manually only, and I haven't yet seen it awarded outside Meta.SE. Are you saying that it'll be awarded to people posting on child metas when they fulfil the criteria?

Comment: @strikers: there is one secret hat that I believe is only being awarded here on Meta.SE, because it is awarded manually and only to the first 7 people to have guessed how to earn the other secret hats.

Comment: @MartijnPieters he's not talking about **getting** the hat, just **wearing** it. and yes, most likely users who got the Eureka hat here on MSE can wear it on any site they want. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: *are all the 8 secret hats are available for grab in that SE site* can easily mean *can I earn the hat on that site*.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: and I know I can wear the Eureka hat on any site because I already did so. :-P

Comment: Fair enough but only @strikers can really confirm what he meant.

Comment: i have seen in leader board some one earned Eureka in in another SE site, not in Meta

Comment: @strikers: Do you have a link?

Comment: He is Logan: http://anime.stackexchange.com/users/24/logan-m#winter-bash

Comment: I got the doubt after seeing it there

Comment: Can any one explain if that hat is reserved only for meta, how did he earn it?

Comment: @strikers: I guess that Logan then posted his take on how to earn a secret hat on that site and not on Meta.SE. Since Logan is a moderator on that site, they probably spoke with a Stack Exchange developer in a chat room for that site and revealed they knew how a secret hat works.

Comment: looks wierd to me. But not unacceptable

Comment: @MartijnPieters: [Mike Miller](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/98602/mike-miller#winter-bash) has his Eureka from Mathematics.SE, but there's no evidence that he publicly disclosed a hat there.

Comment: @nneonneo: usually that means they disclosed it in chat.

Comment: @nneonneo Both Mike and myself disclosed a secret hat   in Math chat; both got Eureka. I think SE staff can monitor chat network-wide for keywords.

Comment: @Behaviour: that's almost NSA-like, lol. Maybe it was just that the mods were listening in.